# Do we need the 'craft' tag?

Tags: discussion

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft

As the SE is about Craft I don't really think the tag is needed, but would be good to hear all your opinions on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Jamie, I totally agree! It's a little silly and redundant for any question on this site to be tagged with [craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft). I had thought that only some spam, or ill-conceived questions, were using those, but the link you posted demonstrates that it's more widely used than that.

I've just done some quick searching, and unfortunately it's nearly impossible to blacklist specific tags. While [technically it can be done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49418/284597), it apparently needs direct intervention from SE developers, and we're better off just [manually killing off that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222599/284597) wherever it appears.

That being said, feel free to re-tag each of those questions however you feel is appropriate! :)

Comment: Cheers Lindsey, it's a shame we can't easily just delete a tag from the site. Unless anyone has any objections, maybe later today I'll go through and remove that tag from all questions, I'll keep on top of it from now on as well and that should hopefully kill it off.

Comment: On reflection I'll only make a few edits a day, I don't want to push all the new and active questions down the feed with my edits as they will just get forgotten about.

Comment: @JamieWade don't you think it would be better to do them all at once? Now you're pushing relevant questions down every day. I'd probably prefer to not have this every day, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @carlcs Yeah that's a fair point. The only reason I was doing a few at a time was because I didn't want to push the newest questions RIGHT down at the bottom if I went through all of them at once :)

Comment: Yep I first thought that this was a good decision, but now it annoys me that this happens every day. You ok with me doing the rest all at one now? Or would you do that, now that almost everyone knows what you're doing there?

Comment: @carlcs Sure, go for it!

Comment: All the work for nothing, tag still exists because there's [one question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/redactorstyles-plugin-not-working) left using it, which I cannot delete because it got migrated to SO. I guess it's only a question of time until more will be added again, because of auto-suggestion. We did our best, @JamieWade! Thanks for bringing this up anyways.

Comment: @carlcs Thanks for going through the remaining questions, that's a shame about that last one!

Comment: Lets hope people don't click it when they notice there's only just one question tagged with it. @JamieWade

Comment: I was able to remove the last "craft" tag. That question was (embarrassingly) accidentally migrated... I've emailed SE support to see if it can be un-migrated.

Comment: Man those guys are fast! Within minutes of emailing them, they'd fixed the problem. I wish I'd contacted them months ago! :)

Comment: @LindseyD Was just about to come on here because I noticed that question had gone! Thanks for your help Lindsey!

Comment: @carlcs Couldn't tag two people in one comment...