# Permanently ban the "craft" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I propose we permanently ban the [craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft) tag, for obvious reasons. The entire website is about Craft CMS, so applying a tag of "craft" does nothing to clarify what the question is really about.

This was actually discussed [about two years ago](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/do-we-need-the-craft-tag), and continues to be an issue. A few minutes ago, I went through and removed the tag from all existing questions (again).

People using this tag fall into one (or both) of these categories...

- **They don't know.** Often these folks are new to Craft CMS, and/or to Stack Exchange itself. They're not certain how to write a question, so they choose the uber-generic "craft" tag out of a lack of understanding. No judgement, we've all been there.
- **They don't care.** These folks are just being lazy. Instead of taking the 10 seconds to think up a more accurate tag, they just slap "craft" on it to meet the minimum requirements.

Regardless, I believe it's time to permanently ban the "craft" tag.

In SE terms, the expression is to ["burninate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/284597) a tag. If there is a consensus on burninating this tag, we'll reach out to an SE rep.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of destroying things and support this 100%.

Comment: Now, with the release of Craft3. Should we re-consider this propose? I think it's best to have at least a craft2 tag. @BradBell

Comment: Have to admit it's been helpful with a large breaking release like Craft 3 to know what people are referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done: the [craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft) tag is no longer in the system, and anyone attempting to recreate it will encounter a bit of guidance:

[image: The 'craft' tag is not allowed. All questions here are relevant to Craft CMS; if your question is ONLY applicable to a specific version, then use the tag for that version only (e.g. craft2)]

There are a small number of untagged questions as a result of this; please give them useful tags: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Thanks @Shog9, that was beginning to drive me a bit crazy. :)

Comment: Done & done... all of the untagged questions have been given tags.

Answer (score 0):

I know my response is really late but I think because of Craft 3 we should keep this tag so people can see if the question is about Craft 3 or Craft 2.

I had the issue a few minutes ago, the creator of a question didn't mention the version he/she uses. In my opinion it's more intuitive for new people to tag those with [craft3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft3) or [craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/craft) to show what it is about.

Comment: I could see having tags for `craft2` or `craft3`, but I still don't see the value of a tag that's simply `craft`. Both versions are "craft", and the entire site is about Craft... if the idea is to have a version-specific tag, then we should be introducing a "craft2" tag instead of keeping "craft".

Comment: Yes of course I totally agree with that. So is it ok to change topics with the craft tag into craft3 and craft2?

Comment: I'd recommend opening a new Meta question on that subject. This question makes a case for destroying the `craft` tag, you're proposing we add a `craft2` tag. It might be a good idea, let's debate it in a separate thread.